# How can I make a fluid simulation in game engine

Tags: fluid-simulation, game-engine

Is there a way to simulate a fluid in the game engine? It doesn't have to be 100% realistic (but not a cycling 2D animation). It just needs to be recognizable as water.

Optimally, there should be a way too make it not very computationally intensive, if it is by default.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. You can't do fluid sim in BGE. Fluid simulation is a complicated process and won't run fast in real-time.

Only if it's built on a graphics card  system, such as CUDA or OpenCL, it might be fast enough. But Blender's fluid system isn't. You might want to check into faking it with particles.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about using particles instead. This might work

Comment: No problem. ;-) Neat to see you on here also, @Luke.

Comment: Could you bake the fluid simulation ahead of time for a static piece of scenery?

Comment: You probably could. But yeah, it would be static.

Comment: I thought there were no particles in the game engine?

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer... But I thought I'd leave it here as a reference for any developer that might want to pick up on an old project:

Ian Johnson has done considerable work to get a working fluid solver (powered by OpenCL) in the Blender game engine. You can see a video of it here: http://enja.org/2011/12/01/rtps-fluid-and-rigid-body-interaction/

The feature never made its way into the official release.