# How do I simulate fluid in the BGE?

Tags: game-engine, fluid-simulation

I am trying to make a game where a player can drive a car. I want to have a lake that the car can drive into and splash. I am not very good with the game engine especially at coding. If I can't simulate the fluid how would I make it so that when the car goes underwater it looks realistic.

Comment: If you've heard about Blender's fluid simulation system, it could do that, but it's really, _really_ slow. I'd go with a particle system, and possibly metaballs if those can be used as particles.

Comment: How would I do it?

Comment: That I don't know. There is [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-can-i-make-a-fluid-simulation-in-game-engine), but they don't have an answer either as of now.